# git push only moved some files

Tags: git

So, I'm a bit of a git noob, but I've been able to get it working for me most of the time.  I've recently encountered a problem that has me stumped. I set up a git repo for a staging site and a production site.  My post-receive file looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/site_name.com/public_html git checkout -f master
```

The only difference in my staging post-receive is it goes to /staging.  I did git init on my local machine, set up the remotes and pushed to staging.  When I was done, I could go to myDomain.com/staging and bam, page loads.  Then I go and push to live and look, and roughly 1/3 of the files are there.

When I load myDomain.com it shows up as a directory.  When I check the files, the index and several directories never made the move.  When I try to do

```
git add .
git commit -m "some message"
git push production master
```

It gives me the message "Everything up-to-date" even though it's clear that it's not.

I've looked at:

```
git status --ignore
```

The only files the come up are the .DS_Store files in each directory.

Any help would be much appreciated.  I'm very stuck.

Comment: You say that the post-receive hook looks "something like" the two lines.  What *exactly* does it look like?  And, you mention staging vs production, but not whether these are separate *repos* on separate *machines*, or just some careful distinction in a single bare repo on a single machine.  This matters a lot...

Comment: The post-receive looks exactly like what is there, except with my actual site name in there.  The production is here: /var/www/site_name.com/public_html/production.git and the staging repo is here: /var/www/site_name.com/public_html/staging/staging.git

Comment: OK, so, two separate repos, that likely eliminates one possibility.  (Specifically, `git checkout` uses the index to decide what files must actually be replaced in the work-tree, so if you've done one checkout, then changed work-tree *locations* without also changing or clearing the index file, git will believe the new location already has the old files.  In the case of deploying one repo to two separate work-trees, this little buglet always bites people.)  But that does mean I'm not sure what else to suggest.

Comment: The worst thing is, I had this set up and working, then my CC expired so I missed payment for 2 weeks and my host dropped my VPS (lost files and setup)... I ended up hopping on filezilla and set up an SSH connection and just moved my files over manually that way. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a .gitignore that makes git ignore certain files.

Comment: Right, which is why I ran git status --ignore, which showed that it was not set to ignore the files that weren't pushed.

Answer (score 0):

When you add the files, which folder are you in? If you're not in the base directory, try:

`git add -A :/`